# React-Virtualized Table onRowClick highlight row

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I am working on React-Virtualized Table, on row selection or on row click I want to highlight the selected row/rows and also provide the unselect option(remove the highlight), it should work how a checkbox row selection works but I don't want to use a Checkbox, any work around for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used rowstyle and I am able to do that.